# How long does google cache the old data for amp-live-list

Tags: caching, amp-html, amp-list

I am implementing amp-live-list for live news.as per ampbyexample.com "New content just needs to be published to the same URL".so i have to publish only new content to same url but this url will lost the old content.

so How long google cache will server the old content or i have to publish old+new contents both to same url?

```
<article>
        <div class="article-head">
            <amp-live-list layout="container" data-poll-interval="500000" data-max-items-per-page="20" id="amp-live-news" class="article-body">
                <button update on="tap:amp-live-list-insert-blog.update">You have updates</button>
                <div items>
                    <div id=@Model.Article.BasicId data-sort-time=@Model.Article.ModifiedDate.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") class="article-body">
                        @Html.Raw(Model.Article.Content)
                    </div>

            </amp-live-list>
        </div>
    </article>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to only push New content. It will take minimum 15 Sec to update.
You can refer below article for more clarity. 
https://ampbyexample-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/ampbyexample.com/components/amp-live-list/?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQCCAE%3D#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=From%20%251%24s&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-live-list%2F

For part update - https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-live-list/amp-live-list-server-side-filtering.md